# Drupal Code Sniffer Not Returning Results

Tags: drupal, phpcodesniffer

When using phpcs -v --standard=Drupal  on a drupal site with coder installed the only results I get are: Registering sniffs in the Drupal standard...

When I use any other standard (Pear, PSR, WordPress, Squiz, etc...) I get results.

Has anyone encournted this before?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe you have to precise version ? D7 and D8 are not the sames

Comment: Never mind, I figured it out. I'm using MAMP and the Drupal libraries in the same location as Code Sniffer.